# What meaning does ** (double asterisk) have in chinese?

Tags: expressions

I'm reading some web novels, and I noticed that once in a while there's ** double asterisk in the middle of a sentence, but I have no idea what they represent.

For example:

```
 **的挑釁
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as in the prude American culture, it is a kind of abominable censorship of certain expletives, like 狗日的 (fucking), 他妈的 (fucking), 我肏 (fuck), 我靠 (fuck) etc.

Comment: How should the asterisks be read aloud then?

Comment: iciba：expletive 咒骂语
2. I mean, I just about ( expletive ) in my pants.
    我的意思是, 我只是在说 ( 咒骂 ) 我的裤子.
3. We're not going to take this ( expletive ) any more.
    我们不能再他妈这样下去了。
4. Please take your seats and shut the ( expletive ) up.
    请你们入座,还有收声 ( 咒骂语 ) 了.